# Devo fazer unit test em classes POCO?

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade

Tenho diversas classes deste tipo:

```
public class Product
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Description { get;set; }
}
```

Estou criando unit tests usando o Xunit, e me surgiu essa duvida: devo fazer unit tests neste tipo de classe?

No time onde trabalho, uns dizem que sim e outros que não.

Comment: E eles responderam porque fazer ou porque não fazer? Se eles não sabem porque decidiram isso eles não sabem do que estão falando. Quem disse que é para fazer, disse como fazem? Mostram os benefícios?

Comment: Os que batem o pé dizendo que precisa fazer, não me convenceram - ficam dando voltas no porque de ter que fazer teste.

Mas de tudo que conheço, creio que nao deve ser feito, só no caso de ter alguma lógica no getter/setter - pelo menos foi o que aprendi com cursos.

Comment: Não há comportamento algum para testar ai... testes se aplicam a métodos em geral, por exemplo o método X "filtra cliente por ID", então esse comportamento é testado, essa classe é simplesmente para trafegar dados, não vejo razão para testar, nem mesmo "o que" testar ai. Se não tiver uma boa razão deveria deixar isso de lado...já tive um problema semelhante, quando usamos Sonar para validar cobertura de testes, e há muitas classes assim e eram marcadas como sem cobertura, dai usamos inclusive o `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` por não fazer sentido testar

Comment: mas como comentou o @Maniero, se te disseram para testar, devem explicar a razão e o benefício disso, ou estão apenas querendo fazer "porque sim"

Comment: @RicardoPontual já expliquei, mas mesmo assim não concordam - entao resolvei fazer pesquisas, para ter provas,  e nao encontrei sobre isso.